# Can Microsoft MVP application additionally have MVC 4.0 application in the same application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, mvp

We have an application in which UI layer has been built with MVP. Can the same solution adapt mvc4.0 application. We are going to create some new pages with specific feature. We would like to make it to adaptable to all the devices(desktop, tablet and mocile device). So we thought having MVC4.0 will do the things for us.

How much it is feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer. Yes. Long answer.. with care. Have a look at hanselmans post:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications